# Why does the Central Treaty Organization include the word "central"?

Tags: cold-war

Recently, I've been wondering, from the 1950s to 1979, there was the Central Treaty Organization, but I don't know why it was named "Central". Do you mean the "center" of the Eurasian Continent?

Comment: See: [Baghdad Pact - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baghdad_Pact): *The Middle East Treaty Organization (METO), also known as the Baghdad Pact and subsequently known as the Central Treaty Organization (CENTO), was a military alliance of the Cold War. It was formed in 24 February 1955 by Iran, Iraq, Pakistan, Turkey, and the United Kingdom. The alliance was dissolved in 16 March 1979.*

Comment: Thank you for giving a comment. However, I've already looked up that information. I would like to ask you, why is it called "central"? Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: The 'Near East', later called the 'Middle East', is named from the perspective of Western Europe. The Wikipedia article on the Middle East says _The term "Middle East" has led to some confusion over its changing definitions, and has been viewed by some to be discriminatory[2] or too Eurocentric._ Maybe that is why the name of the organisation was changed to 'Central'.

Comment: @瀬川大地 This site prefers questions with some form of previous research with sources. I added that source for the benefit of **others**, since you made no attempt to explain what **Central Treaty Organization** is and that it recieved that name only after Iraq in 1958 withdrew from, what until then, was called the **Baghdad Pact**. All of this should have been included in your question as background information.

Comment: Please move all the information from the comments into the question.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about it.
I asked the reference at the New York library and the answer was "We don't know", but with this site I can get the best response within 24 hours. I am very happy

Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

The *Central* part of the naming of the Central Treaty Organization has to do with its association with other anti-communist leagues set up in that same time frame. You can see the association in a State Department publication [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=F4W3ek8x8qEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Central+Treaty+Organization&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEiZnC2Iz9AhUTLkQIHbE3CiwQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> **ORIGIN**  The Central Treaty Organization CENTO began, as did its earlier regional sister alliances- the North Atlantic Treaty
> Organization NATO in 1949 and the Southeast Asia Treaty Organization
> SEATO in 1954, as a response of free peoples to the threat from
> communism. The establishment of the alliance demonstrated the
> determination of the countries of the northern tier to preserve their
> independence by resisting Communist aggression or subversive penetration and by working together for stability In addition to membership
> in CENTO Turkey belongs to NATO and Pakistan is a member of SEATO

So ***Central*** *Treaty Organization* (CENTO) was associated with ***North Atlantic*** *Treaty Organization* (NATO) and ***Southeast Asian*** *Treaty Organization* (SEATO) to show the widespread geographic nature of the fight against the spread of communism. The consistent naming style is just there to provide a connection to the other organizations, therefore showing the unity in purpose of the organizations. This similarity in name choice is also noted in the [Encyclopedia of the Cold War](https://books.google.com/books?id=xNEI5CEZX-UC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT185&dq=central%20treaty%20organization%20name%20change&pg=PT185#v=onepage&q&f=true) (emphasis mine):

> Consequently, the Pact was renamed the Central Treaty Organization
> (Cento) on Aug 21, 1959, and its headquarters were removed from
> Baghdad to the Turkish capital Ankara. This name change ***highlighted
> the organizations similarities*** to the North Atlantic Treaty
> Organization (NATO) and the Southeast Asian Treaty Organization
> (SEATO), underscoring its cold war origins, and perhaps further
> undermining its credibility.

A footnote from another source [The Arab Nationalist Advisor: Yusuf Yassin of Saudi Arabia](https://books.google.com/books?id=03ugEAAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA259&dq=central%20treaty%20organization%20name%20change&pg=PA259#v=onepage&q=central%20treaty%20organization%20name%20change&f=true),By Joseph A. Kéchichian, goes as far as pointing out the central positioning of this alliance between NATO and SAETO (emphasis mine):

> CENTO was redefined as a conventional military alliance in the Cold
> War climate of the 1950s, and served as the ***central link*** in the
> chain of strategic defense pacts against the Soviet Union and it
> allies, established by the Western powers from the North Atlantic
> Treaty Organization (NATO) to the Southeast Asian Treaty Organization
> (SEATO).

They might have used ***Middle Eastern*** (METO?), but *Central* has a similar meaning to Middle, and could imply a wider, more expansive, less restrictive membership. It *sounds* better, is more inclusive, and accented its connection to the other organizations.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. It was the central link between NATO and SEATO. This was a tactic of the 'western' forces to enclose the USSR with friendly countries. This is why the war in Afghanistan from '79-'89 was so important to both sides (the USSR and the US). The west was worried the USSR would move into Iran and/or Pakistan after breaking them out from their near total blockade. This is why the CIA exerted so much time, money, and effort to help the Afghans.